# How to stay hover color after pressed

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using sahifa theme.I set special css for each buton on main menu.But something block my code and it's back to orjinal theme color blue.

I tried every rules

```
    /* Altinci Menu */
.altinci-nav{

    /*background-color: #866;*/
}   

.altinci-nav:hover {
  background-color: #8c5de4;    
}

/*ul li.altinci-nav a,*/
.altinci-nav ul li a:hover,
.altinci-nav ul li a,
.altinci-nav ul li:hover > a,
.altinci-nav ul li:active,
ul li.altinci-nav:active{
    background-color: #8c5de4;
}
.altinci-nav:active {
  background-color: #8c5de4;    
}
.altinci-nav:focus {
  background-color: #8c5de4;    
}

.altinci-nav:select{
     background-color: #8c5de4; 
}

.altinci-nav:after{
     background-color: #8c5de4; 
}
```

I look with firefox web developer tools and it's show problem that.

```
#main-nav ul li.current-menu-item a,
#main-nav ul li.current-menu-item a:hover
```

So I make comment this lines bu nothing change

**UPDATE**

```
 #main-nav ul li.current-menu-item a, 
    #main-nav ul li.current-menu-item a:hover{ background-color: transparent !important; }
```

Thank you.Claudiu D.

Comment: do u have a live link?

Comment: check the code after it is displayed blue. there might be a rule more precise then yours which overwrites you. If you find it --> make your selector as precise. you can also try the lazy, but less suggested variant !important

Comment: I add my css link can you check please.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find your .altinci-nav:hover css rule and add a chained one for the current page like this

```
.altinci-nav:hover,
.altinci-nav.current-menu-item {
```

do the same for other links

Comment: It's work, but my box appearing under to original box.I'dont want orjinal box.Check: http://www.onbilim.com/category/kesfet/

Comment: i think this one is generated by WP because i see it in index page at line 109, (i can't copy paste as it's to long for comments box) but it has background-color: #37b8eb; as property for the css rule, if u remove this property the button will have full color

Comment: by the way because it's in index page and not in a css file, it's a high chance that it's generated by the WP theme, so you would have better luck if u look in WP-Admin on theme settings for some nav links colors that have this value #37b8eb, delete it and try like that, rather than overriding the CSS file

Comment: As you say this code generated by WP. reading-position-indicator  {
 background-color:#37b8eb;
}
But,there is no settings for that on admin.Theme setting just change the color blue or another color but no settings for that.

Comment: this is the rule u have to override "#main-nav ul li.current-menu-item a" set the bg value to "background-color: transparent !important;" if u can't find a way to do it from wp-admin, i would recommend looking more in admin there must be a section from where to delete that color

Comment: It's work 
#main-nav ul li.current-menu-item a,
#main-nav ul li.current-menu-item a:hover{
background-color: transparent !important;
 }
Thank you Claudiu :)